# Javascript tab is not getting active properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have three tabs, whose active/inactive class is coming from the javascript code. But when I click on the second or third tab, it moves to the first tab. See my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs1').each(function () {
            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
            $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content = $($active[0].hash);
            $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $(this.hash).hide();
            });
            $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $content.hide();
                $active = $(this);
                $content = $(this.hash);
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.show();
            });
        });
    });
```

Also see the html for the same

```
<ul class='tabs1'>
            <li><a href='#tab1' id="allNews" runat="server" onserverclick="allNews_ServerClick">All News</a></li>

            <li><a href='#tab2' id="forNgo" runat="server" onserverclick="forNgo_ServerClick">For NGO</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab3' id="fromNgo" runat="server" onserverclick="fromNgo_ServerClick">From NGO</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Whenver I click to the `second` or `third` tab, It agains move to the first tab.

**UPDATE**

Postback pageload code:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            HtmlAnchor HA = new HtmlAnchor();
            HA.ServerClick += new EventHandler(allNews_ServerClick);

            HtmlAnchor HA2 = new HtmlAnchor();
            HA2.ServerClick += new EventHandler(forNgo_ServerClick);

            HtmlAnchor HA3 = new HtmlAnchor();
            HA3.ServerClick += new EventHandler(fromNgo_ServerClick);

            BindNews();

        }
    }
```

The three tabs serverclick code:-

```
protected void ddlSortOrder_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            //string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost) = " + ddlYear.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost " + ddlSortOrder.SelectedValue;
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost) = " + ddlYear.SelectedValue + " ORDER BY dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost " + ddlSortOrder.SelectedValue;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void allNews_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set user type accordingly in all below methods
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, dbo.tbl_User.usertype FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_User ON dbo.tbl_post.userId = dbo.tbl_User.Id where usertype != '2'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
            allNews.Attributes["class"] = "active";
        }
    }
    protected void forNgo_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, dbo.tbl_User.usertype FROM dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_User ON dbo.tbl_post.userId = dbo.tbl_User.Id where usertype != '2'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
            forNgo.Attributes["class"] = "active";
        }
    }
    protected void fromNgo_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT dbo.tbl_post.Id, dbo.tbl_post.title, dbo.tbl_post.description, dbo.tbl_post.dateforPost, dbo.tbl_ngoname.ngo_name, dbo.tbl_User.usertype FROM  dbo.tbl_post INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ngoname ON dbo.tbl_post.NgoId = dbo.tbl_ngoname.Id INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_User ON dbo.tbl_post.userId = dbo.tbl_User.Id where usertype = '2'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            lstNews.DataSource = dt;
            lstNews.DataBind();
            fromNgo.Attributes["class"] = "active";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a problem when I load it up in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/0aez0f5h/

Comment: @EnigmaRM: My tab gets active, but it again move to the first tab. See my postback code also in few mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you should refer to `e.target` rather than `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.tabs1').each(function () {
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active[0].hash);
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $(this.hash).hide();
        });
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();
            $active = $(e.target);
            $content = $(location.hash);
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();
        });
    });
});
```

Also you should use `e.preventDefault()` to halt the default click event. In terms of style, I would not recommend using $ for variables, too close to jQuery $ usage and not a convention to do this.

Comment: can you give me the correct code with updated one. As I am confused here what to use and what to not

Comment: Just replace this small section, the click handler.

Comment: can you please update in the answer, so if it works I can mark it as answer :)

Comment: did you added `e.preventDefault()` ??

Comment: Now my respective tab is getting active, but the relevant data is not coming

Comment: Yes, and also changed two other lines. I'm hoping that does not prevent the hash from appearing in the browser url, fingers crossed.

Comment: Problem solved then, this is an HTML, jQuery and JavaScript question. You should test your server callback separately, seems like a different issue.

Comment: The hash is not appearing in the browser, but I m unable to see the relevant data when the respective tab is clicked

Comment: I don't know how your client > server > client magic works, so can't really recommend anything. The original question is solved though right?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will mark it and will debug that and check..!! Thannks Ian Jones.

Comment: Thank you! please also upvote for useful answer. I need all the credits I can get atm :)

Comment: I still can't upvote as I have less points and Stack has terms for upvoting :)